# Flow of a Vector Field

Tags: vector-fields

If $V_r$ be a vector field defined on $S^2_r$ that is always tangent to the sphere on which it is defined.Define a vector field $V$ on $R^3$ such that $V(x)$=$r^2(1-r^2)$$V_r(x)$.Prove that for each $t \in R$ the time $t$ flow associated to this vector field is defined.

Comment: But there is no smooth vector field on $S^2$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem

Comment: @MichaelHoppe:  There are plenty of smooth vector fields on $S^2$.  There are no smooth *non-vanishing* vector fields on $S^2$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, of course.

Comment: Here's a hint for the problem.  Let $\gamma$ denote the flow through some point.  Prove $|\gamma|$ is constant, so the flow lies on whatever sphere bout the origin it starts on.  In particular, since the sphere is compact, flows on it last for all time.

Comment: @Ester:  The idea seems to be correct, but I'm not sure about a couple of the details:  I don't understand how you go from $x_0$ to $(0,x_0)$.  Further, you need to prove the the curve lies on a sphere - just because it starts on a sphere doesn't mean it lies on a sphere for all time.  I also don't understand your last question - to me, the flow is nothing but the collection of all integral curves.

Comment: @Jason:How will I show that |gamma| is 1?

Comment: Your notation is somewhat fishy. Does $V_r$ live only one particular sphere of radius $r$? Then what does $V_r(x)$ mean for arbitrary $x\in{\mathbb R}^3$? What does the factor $r^2(1-r^2)$ ("here $r$ is varying") mean in connection with $x$?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter:Sorry for the confusion.I have edited.

Comment: @Ester:  Start with $f(t) = |\gamma(t)|^2$.  Then $f'(t) = 2\langle \gamma(t), \gamma'(t)\rangle = 2\langle \gamma(t), V(\gamma(t))\rangle = 2\langle \gamma(t), f(t)(1-f(t)) V_r(\gamma(t))$.  Since $V_r(\gamma(t))$ is tangent to the sphere, what do you know about this?

Comment: @JAson:Thanks for your ideas and corrections.

Comment: @Ester:  You might consider writing up your answer here.  It might save you some bounty points ;-).  Glad I could help!